# Apache Ignite: Serialization error related to Data Streaming

Tags: java, classloader, gridgain, ignite

I am trying to investigate how Apache Ignite streaming works. I have 2 nodes cluster setup (both on localhost), and I start a client node which runs streaming code with StreamTransformer and EntryProcessor. As a result in one of my nodes I get cannot deserialize exception. My code is simplified WordCount example from Ignite documentation:

```
public class StreamingExample {`
public static class StreamingExampleCacheEntryProcessor implements CacheEntryProcessor<String, Long, Object> {
    @Override
    public Object process(MutableEntry<String, Long> e, Object... arg) throws EntryProcessorException {
        Long val = e.getValue();
        e.setValue(val == null ? 1L : val + 1);
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException, IOException {
    Ignition.setClientMode(true);
    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {
        IgniteCache<String, Long> stmCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("mycache");
        try (IgniteDataStreamer<String, Long> stmr = ignite.dataStreamer(stmCache.getName())) {
            stmr.allowOverwrite(true);
            stmr.receiver(StreamTransformer.from(new StreamingExampleCacheEntryProcessor()));
            stmr.addData("word", 1L);
            System.out.println("Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Exception I get one ONE of two nodes is

> [23:38:23] Topology snapshot [ver=5, servers=2, clients=1, CPUs=4, heap=3.3GB]
>   Exception in thread "pub-#9%null%" class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1595)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1663)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:298)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal(BinaryMarshaller.java:109)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.processRequest(DataStreamProcessor.java:278)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor.access$000(DataStreamProcessor.java:50)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastreamer.DataStreamProcessor$1.onMessage(DataStreamProcessor.java:80)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1238)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:866)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1700(GridIoManager.java:106)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:829)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling (make sure same versions of all classes are avai
>   lable on all nodes or enable peer-class-loading): sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e857327
>           at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal(OptimizedMarshaller.java:224)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadOptimized(BinaryUtils.java:1592)
>           ... 13 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gridgaingames.StreamingExample$StreamingExampleCacheEntryProcessor
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8350)
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextAdapter.getClass(MarshallerContextAdapter.java:185)
>           at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshallerUtils.classDescriptor(OptimizedMarshallerUtils.java:266)
>           at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:318)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364)
>           at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readFields(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:491)
>           at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readSerializable(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:579)
>           at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedClassDescriptor.read(OptimizedClassDescriptor.java:841)
>           at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(OptimizedObjectInputStream.java:324)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364)
>           at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller.unmarshal(OptimizedMarshaller.java:218)
>           ... 14 more

There are several things I cannot get.

1) How can I fix it?

2) As this is not not "broadcast" or something, I supposed Ignite runs Streaming code on calling node only. Looks like I was wrong. So where my Streaming code is executed?

3) After printing "Finished" line my code doesn't stop. Why? Looks like some non-daemon thread is still there. Is this a Streaming code which prevents my client node from exiting?

PS

peer classloading is enabled. if I run some example with broadcast which executes code on many nodes - it works ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `IgniteDataStreamer` prepares data batches on a sender side (client side in your example) and sends them right away to destination nodes that should store specific key-value tuples. Keeping this in mind the answers for your questions will be the following:

1. Transformers are executed on destination nodes (server nodes) before an entry is placed into a cache. It means that a server node must have transformer's class in its classpath or, alternatively, you have to enable peer-class-loading. Personally, the latter is more flexible and preferable solution.
2. As it's explained above a sender simply prepares batches that are sent to all the servers where a cache is deployed. Servers receive only those batches that contain tuples for which a server is a primary or backup one.
3. Flushing of the batches happens in background because `IgniteDataStreamer` is used for fast data pre-loading or complex streaming processing (CEP). There are a number of parameters that let you tune the flushing - `autoFlustFrequency`, `perNodeBufferSize`.

Lastly, for pre-loading needs (when caches are empty and you need fill them up) I would suggest setting `allowOverwrite` to `false` which will allow the streamer to prepare and sending batches for primary and backup nodes separately. If this parameter is set to `true` then the batches are sent on primary nodes only and primary nodes injects data with basic `cache.put` operations after that updating its version of data and corresponding backups. This approach is slower if you just need to pre-load your caches.

Comment: Thanks, dmagda! But I cannot find the answer to my main question on ClassNotFoundException. PeerToPeer classloading is enabled (as you see I am using one of configuration which ship with Ignite - examples/config/example-ignite.xml). Still I get this error. I have a guess that may be Transformer's code is started BEFORE Transformer's class is actually received by the node. Is this the rootcause, or something else? And how to fix it?

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3935). Thank for reporting! Please refer to the suggested workaround that is in the ticket.